# Get username from basic-auth mechanism in Traefik/Streamlit/Docker app

Tags: python, docker, basic-authentication, traefik, streamlit

I'm using Traefik/Streamlit/Docker stack in my ML project.

I want to use basic-auth mechanism to get a Username variable, that user provides to basic-auth, and use it in Streamlit app to provide the information that particular user needs. Is there any way to do that or, maybe, I can use any other Auth apps to solve it.